# I am using the LiveServer extension on VS Code to visualize my three js web application on the browser. I want to build a .exe for same

Tags: express, vscode-extensions, executable, threejs-editor, atom-liveserver

I did not install all the dependencies required to run three js on my local system and started using LiveServer extension available on VS Code. Now, I am trying to build an executable file for this web application that can be run on any desktop. How should I proceed with this.

I did come across frameworks like [Express JS](https://expressjs.com/) but not sure how feasible that is. I am new to this tech stack and open to suggestions.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.